# Clear Page Session State Using Javascript after call apex_server_process in Oracle Application Express (APEX)

Tags: javascript, ajax, oracle-apex

Oracle database Version - 12.2

Oracle Apex Version - 19.2

I Have a Ajax Call Pl/Sql Process in Page Level. and I have Created a javascript function to call apex.server_process Like Below

```
function SaveUser() {

    apex.server.process("USER_CREATION", {

      // p_clob_01:clob,

        pageItems: "#P225_USER_CODE,#P225_USER_NAME,#P225_USER_TYPE,#P225_USER_DOB,#P225_MOBILE_NO,#P225_TELE_NO,#P225_EMAIL_ID,#P225_RESTRICT_FROM_DT,#P225_RESTRICT_TO_DT,#P225_PWD_DATE,#P225_FINGER,#P225_PASSWORD_EXP_DAY,#P225_ROLE_SCOPE,#P225_BRANCH,#P225_USER_ID" /*List of the items that are used in your process */

    }, {

        success: function(pData) {

            if (pData.success === true) {

                apex.message.showPageSuccess(pData.message);

            } else {

              apex.message.clearErrors();

          apex.message.showErrors([{

                    type: "error",

                    location: "page",

                    message:pData.message,

                    unsafe: false

                }]);

            }



        }

    });

    lSpinner$.remove();

  }

}
```

Its Working Fine. But when I Submit the process It Save Data into Db. If I Submit again it Call the process with same Data. It Save the Session State Value.

How Can I Clear Session State and Clear Page without Submiting Page again for pl/sql clear Cache. Is the Any Javascript API For Clear Cache Page after call Apex.server_process.

Please help if you have any idea.

Comment: A normal flow would be to submit the page to create the user. If there are validation errors, they would be displayed on the form page for the user to fix and try again. If successful, the user would be redirected to another page that shows the success message. You have changed the processing to Ajax, which doesn't do the redirect on success. Why did you do that? What is the flow you expect the user to do?

Comment: @Dan McGhan. I know the regular procrss. But i don't want to reload the page or don't want to redirect another page. I want to submit only data not whole page. Thats why i have used apex.server process.

Comment: I'm just trying to get a better understanding of what you're doing and what you want before I offer suggestions. Why do you not want to submit the page or redirect after? What should the user see after a new record is inserted?

Comment: User will see a message. And the the page will be ready for new insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in the same process that saves the data

After the process that saves the data:

- Create a new process that clears the session variables
- (optional) Add a server side condition so it will run only when you need it.
- (optional) Add success and error messages to confirm that you code worked.

IMHO, I don't see a point to clear the cache with JavaScript, but if you really still need it. You could do a `window.location =` to clear the page, app, session variables as defined in the documentation for [managing session variables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_ses_val.htm#HTMDB03014)